# python - Optional argument goofing with eval()

Tags: eval, argparse, optional-arguments

I am trying to parse with argparse. I have a optional argument, called TileScheme:

```
parser.add_argument("--TileScheme", "--TS", default = PuertoRico2018)
```

I want to use the input from this argument as an object, so I do this:

```
TileScheme = eval(args.TileScheme)
```

However, because its an optional argument with a default value, I often don't want to write in the optional argument. I want to pass just numeric values. However, I get this error message when I do that:

```
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object
```

It says this even though that eval() is modifying an optional argument! What to do???

Cheers! O.Fried

Comment: `args.TileScheme` will either the `PuertoRico2018` object (what ever that is), or the string that your user provided.  I suggest doing a `print(args)` so you have a clear idea of what the parser is doing.  Your processing code needs to take that into account.

Comment: If  `TileScheme` is supposed to a  number, then `int(args.TileScheme)` (or `float()`) is better than `eval`.  You could also use `type=int` in the parser.  If the `default` is not a string, it won't apply the `type` to it.

Comment: its supposed to be a string. and i get 'namespace(TileScheme=<__main__.TileScheme instance at 0x7f85a6f2e878>, X_coordinate=-60.1, Y_coordinate=18.4)' when I do print(args)...

Comment: the problem I really have is that the program is treating TileScheme as a positional argument when it should be optional..

Comment: thanks so much though!

Comment: Your `PuertoRico2018` is apparently a `TileScheme` instance.  `args.TileScheme` will be set to that default value when the user does not provide a value himself.  A `positional` doesn't use a `default` (unless you specify a special `nargs`).

Comment: You might find it easier to leave off the `default`.  That way, `args.TileScheme` will be `None` if the users doesn't use it.  Then you can easily do a conditional eval: `TileScheme = eval(args.TileScheme) if args.TileScheme is not None else PuertoRico`

Comment: can you show this in a code block so it is more clear for me?

Answer (score 0):

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--TileScheme", "--TS")
args = parser.parse_args()

TileScheme = eval(args.TileScheme) if args.TileScheme is not None else PuertoRico
```

Or if it is clear to you:

```
if args.TileScheme is None:
    TileScheme = PuertoRico
else:
    TileScheme = eval(TileScheme)
```

---

```
In [116]: import argparse
```

define a class instance:

```
In [118]: class Foo():
     ...:     pass
     ...: 
In [119]: PR = Foo()
In [120]: PR
Out[120]: <__main__.Foo at 0x7f4cd94cd518>
```

The parser:

```
In [121]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [122]: parser.add_argument('-f',default=PR);
```

Without arguments:

```
In [123]: args = parser.parse_args([])
In [124]: print(args)
Namespace(f=<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f4cd94cd518>)
```

eval of the string works, but so does plain `args.f`:

```
In [125]: eval('args.f')
Out[125]: <__main__.Foo at 0x7f4cd94cd518>
In [126]: args.f
Out[126]: <__main__.Foo at 0x7f4cd94cd518>
```

Now with a user defined string:

```
In [128]: args = parser.parse_args(['-f','PR'])
In [129]: args
Out[129]: Namespace(f='PR')
In [130]: eval('args.f')     # eval of the string doesn't help
Out[130]: 'PR'
In [131]: eval(args.f)       # eval of the value does
Out[131]: <__main__.Foo at 0x7f4cd94cd518>
```

Instead of the `None` test I proposed early you could do an `isinstance` test:

```
In [132]: if isinstance(args.f, Foo):
     ...:     print(args.f)
     ...: else:
     ...:     print(eval(args.f))
     ...:     
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f4cd94cd518>
In [133]: args = parser.parse_args([])
In [134]: if isinstance(args.f, Foo):
     ...:     print(args.f)
     ...: else:
     ...:     print(eval(args.f))
     ...:     
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f4cd94cd518>
```

Or alternatively test if `args.f` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

OOPS: i had to write `TileScheme = eval("args.TileScheme")` with the quotes :) thanks for the help though @hpaulj!!

Comment: I don't see how `eval` of the quoted string helps.  See my edit.